# Multiple forms on a single page cakephp with one submit

Tags: forms, cakephp

So I want to do something like this:

```
for($i=1; $i <= 30; $i++)
    echo $form->Create('Sales');
    echo $form->input('price');
    echo $form->input ......

endfor;
echo->$form('submit');
```

And what should get sent to a controller is an array of 30 arrays all of type sales.
Currently only getting one array back--data from the last form.
So on every iteration on the loop it is overwriting the previous form.

Comment: your syntax looks pretty wrong - please stick to coding guidelines. this way you can get a lot of errors

Answer (score 1):

You should not repeat FORM  ,just repeat TEXT FIELD
like below

```
    echo $form->Create('Sales');
    for($i=1; $i = 30; $i++)
      echo $form->input('Sales.'$i'.price');
      echo $form->input ......
    endfor;
    echo->$form('submit');
```

Comment: This post is pretty old. But i have the same doubt. Following your method, how should i post data in the controller? I have one single form with multiple instance of different fields!

Answer (score 0):

To post data, in SalesController

```
public function add(){
    ...
    $this->Sales->saveMany($this->request->data);
    ...
```